# ASP.NET MVC - bug on razor when displaying single quote

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I just noticed when I do something like this:

```
@{
    String var1 = "there's error to this string";
}

<script>
    alert('@var1');
</script>
```

when I start running this and I look at alert box, the single quote character is transforming into weird display starting with #.

but when I just directly placing the string value to alert box, it works as expected:

```
<script>
    alert("there's error to this string");
</script>
```

I hope somebody could explain here why it happens.

Comment: Look at your quotes.  You need to escape the string.

Comment: You're seeing HTML entity encoding.

Comment: @Slaks - I already did that but it still displays the weird character.

Comment: Its not a bug - its doing exactly what it should be doing. In addition to SLaks' answer you can also use `alert(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(var1)))`

Answer (score 2):

You need to Javascript-encode the string, then tell Razor not to HTML-encode it:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(var1))
```